# If Γ ⊢ A, then Γ ⊨ A

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, proof-theory

I'm having a difficult time **differentiating** between the two proofs:

**1. If Γ ⊢ A, then Γ ⊨ A**

vs.

**2. If ⊢ A, then ⊨ A**

**Here's the question:**

Prove “strong soundness”: for any set of formulas, Γ, and any formula A, if Γ ⊢ A then Γ ⊨ A (i.e., if A is provable from Γ then A is a semantic consequence of Γ.)

For 2. If ⊢ A, then ⊨ A, I know that I can prove this using an inductive proof for soundness.

**Here's a proof of If ⊢ A, then ⊨ A**

Proof: I want to show that the axioms (below) have the property of validity. When I show that, I can conclude that every theorem (formulas that are provable from no premises at all) has the property of validity:

1. P->(Q->P) PL1
2. (P->(Q->X))->(P->Q)->(P->X)) PL2
3. (~Q->~P)->((~Q->P)->Q) PL3

**Base case:**

- I show that every axiom is valid.
- For 1), I assume for reductio that P->(Q->P) is invalid for some interpretation Vi
- Vi(P->(Q->P))=0, Thus, Vi(P)=1 and Vi(Q->P)=0 by the definition of conditional. Use the conditional definition again, and I get Vi(Q)=1 and Vi(P)=0
- I see a contradiction of Vi(P)=1 and Vi(P)=0
- Therefore P->(Q->P) is valid.

I would show that 2) and 3) are also valid

**Induction Step:**

- Inductive hypothesis: I assume that every line in a proof up to a certain point is valid. I also assume that modus ponens preserves validity when I show that I can get the consequent if I have the conditional and its antecedent.
- If I assume the inductive hypothesis, I have some formula P which I got from Q->P and Q.
- I want to show that P is a valid formula.
- By the inductive hypothesis, all prior lines are valid, therefore Q->P is and Q are valid
- Thus, for some interpretation, Vi, Vi(Q->P)=1 and Vi(Q)=1
- If Vi(Q)=1, then when we break down Vi(Q->P) with our definition of conditional, Vi(Q)=1 and Vi(P)=1 because that'll make Vi(Q->P)=1
- Therefore Vi(P)=1 which is what I wanted to show
- With this induction proof, I was able to show that If ⊢ A, then ⊨ A

**My question is how would I write a proof for If Γ ⊢ A, then Γ ⊨ A?
What does "strong soundness" mean?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between $\vdash A$ and $\Gamma \vdash A$ is that in the latter, you are allowed to use statements in $\Gamma$ as well as the axioms in your proof of $A$. The difference between $\models A$ and $\Gamma \models A$ is that in the latter, $A$ need only be true in all interpretations that satisfy $\Gamma,$ rather than in every interpretation.

So to prove $\Gamma \models A,$ you only need to consider interpretations that satisfy $\Gamma,$ but there is a wider class of proofs to check. Everything is very similar. You need to show every axiom is true in any interpretation satisfying $\Gamma,$ but you've already shown they are true in every interpretation period, so that's done. Now that you are allowed to use statements in $\Gamma,$ you need to show that all of these are true in any interpretation satisfying $\Gamma.$ But that is an immediate consequence of what it means for an interpretation to satisfy $\Gamma$.

Finally, following the same logic as in your induction step, you need to show that modus ponens preserves the property of being true in every interpretation satisfying $\Gamma$ (i.e. if $\Gamma\models A$ and $\Gamma \models A\to B,$ then $\Gamma\models  B$). I'll leave it to you to check that essentially the same proof you gave goes through under these slightly different circumstances.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, things make more sense. To follow up, what do you mean by statements when you say can use them in Γ when you're describing the difference between ⊢ and  Γ ⊢? Are these statements similar to premises that are inside of Γ? Also, when you say to show that the statements are true in Γ, would I do something similar to what I did in the inductive hypothesis? If I had a statement/premise Q->P which was in Γ, would I do Vi(Q->P)=1 and show that it's true in the proof A?

Comment: By "statements in $\Gamma$" I mean you use the statements that are in $\Gamma$ (i.e. the premises) in the proof. I don't mean that $\Gamma$ is the place that you use the statements. I never said to show that the statements are true in $\Gamma$ (that is nonsense), I said to show that they are true in any interpretation that satisfies $\Gamma.$

Comment: It seems to me like you are further from understanding than your correct proof of (1) suggests. I would guess you're having trouble understanding the role of $\Gamma$ in general. If you want further help, I request you write out the precise definition of $\Gamma\vdash A$ and $\Gamma\models A$ that you are working off of (doesn't need to be super detailed), so I can match your terminology (and it will probably be helpful for you as well).

Comment: For Γ⊢, the definition I'm using is: "A is provable from Γ, that there exists some axiomatic proof of A from Γ" For Γ ⊨ , the definition I'm using is: "A is a PL-semantic consequence of Γ if and only if A is true whenever each member of Γ is true"

Comment: By "interpretation satisfies $\Gamma$" I mean that each sentence of $\Gamma$ is true in the interpretation. Does that help? For the $\Gamma\vdash A$ part, I was more looking for what a proof from $\Gamma$ means. It seems like you are using a Hilbert system, and so what it means is simply that in addition to using any axiom instance, you are allowed to use any sentence from $\Gamma.$ So your "base cases" now include those sentences as well as the axioms. (But it is obvious that every sentence in $\Gamma$ is true in any interpretation where all the members of $\Gamma$ are true.)

Comment: For $\Gamma \vdash A$ you have to review the definition of [Formal deduction (or: derivation)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Dedu).